# regex jquery for IDnumber if match then enable button

Tags: javascript, jquery

i don't know much regex so if some one can help me with this it would be great i have a input box and a button.
if the user enters `A12345678` the first character should always be A and the rest should always be numbers and altogether it should have less then 10 characters

```
<input type="textbox" id="id" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*Check if ID is correct  */
      $('#id').keyup(function(){
            var id= $(this).val();
            if(id == /*'A12345678' */{
               //enable button 
            }else{
               // disable button
        });
    </script>
```

i would appreciate if some one could help me out a bit with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go `^(A\d{1,9})$`;

`^` will start the verification at the beginning of the string

`()` encapsulates your result. not necessarily needed, but I like to have them

`A` will match the uppercase character

`\d{1, 9}` will match 1 to 9 numbers following the letter A

`$`means the end of the string

Use:

```
if(id.match(/^(A\d{1,9})$/)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Hope this helps.

Watch it work: https://jsfiddle.net/ppmr12v6/

Comment: do you know how would i do this in php

Comment: `preg_match("/^(S\d{1,9})$/)",$username) `
is this correct